# Error para guardar un dato desde PHP a una Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo un problema para guardar un dato en una BD, resulta que este codigo me había funcionado hace un ratico pero ya no lo hace de forma correcta y siempre me devuelve un error, quisiera saber una forma de corregirlo o al menos una forma de ver que error es y así buscar una solución mas precisa, espero que puedan ayudarme, de ante mano Gracias!

Codigo php

```
<?php

    include 'conexion.php';

    $name = $_POST['inputNameR'];
    $ape = $_POST['inputApeR'];
    $email = $_POST['inputEmailR'];
    $phone = $_POST['inputPhoneR'];
    $password = $_POST['inputPasswordR'];
    $passwordConfirm = $_POST['inputPasswordRR'];

    if ($password == $passwordConfirm) {
        $sqlEmail = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$email'";
        $result = $conexion->query($sqlEmail);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $verification = 2;
        } else {
            $sqlRegister = "INSERT INTO users (name, last_name, email, celphone, purchases, password, role) VALUES ('$name', '$ape', '$email', '$phone', 0, sha1($password), 1)";
            if ($conexion->query($sqlRegister) == true) {
                $verification = 3;
            } else {
                $verification = 4;
            }
        }
     } else {
    $verification = 1;
     }
    echo $verification;

    ?>

´´´

En este codigo siempre guarda en la variable el numero 4 que indica un error
```

Comment: Vale, Disculpa si la eliminé por error

Comment: Revisaste que la sql este bien redactada en $sqlRegister?.

Comment: Si, está bien redactada, además de que habia funcionado hace un rato, Mi idea es buscar una forma de guardar el error, que me lo muestre por consola o algo similar

Comment: Ok, pero estas usando algún framework?.

Comment: No que yo sepa... Es puro php en Sublime Text, y para diseño uso Bootstrap

Comment: Bueno en el entorno de desarrollo en php, se opta por mostrar los errores directamente en la web, pero en producción php y apache tiene una forma de manejar los errores, la cual es guardando los en un archivo .log.

Comment: Porque no usas try catch para manejar los errores, [aquí mas información](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: ¿Qué API estás usando para conectar a MySQL, `PDO` o `mysqli`? Por el uso de `num_rows` parece que es `mysqli` pero es bueno que lo confirmes para poder ayudarte con una respuesta basada en esa API.

Answer (score 0):

De un vistazo rápido y según el comentario del código:

> En este codigo siempre guarda en la variable el numero 4 que indica un error

Tiene pinta de ser `sha1($password)` dentro de la consulta *INSERT*, que es un *string* y debería ir entre comillas.

Cambia:

```
"INSERT INTO users (name, last_name, email, celphone, purchases, password, role) VALUES ('$name', '$ape', '$email', '$phone', 0, sha1($password), 1)";
```

[Un ejemplo de la salida del *string* en un *PHP sandbox*](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b5cc999b0cbc11629e92adf15f958c6a6903db04)

Por:

```
"INSERT INTO users (name, last_name, email, celphone, purchases, password, role) VALUES ('$name', '$ape', '$email', '$phone', 0,'". sha1($password) ."', 1)";
```

O una alternativa:

```
$password = sha1($password);
$sqlRegister = "INSERT INTO users (name, last_name, email, celphone, purchases, password, role) VALUES ('$name', '$ape', '$email', '$phone', 0, '$password', 1)";
```

Prueba y nos cuentas.